# How to create column of type password in gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, passwords

I am creating an application in which user selects files and provides credentials to open that file. For that I have created three columns in a gridview.
User enters password in password column.
I want to display **`*`** in place of characters like we can create a textbox of password type.
I have tried this code on `GridView_CellClick` event :

```
if (GridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "Password")
{ 
   txtPassword[e.RowIndex] = new TextBox();
   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Name = "txtPassword"+e.RowIndex;
   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].PasswordChar = '*';
   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Visible = true;
   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].TextChanged += new      

   if (GridView.CurrentCell.Value == null)
      txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Text = "";
   else
      txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Text = GridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Location = GridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex + 1, false).Location;

   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Size = GridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex + 1, false).Size;

   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Visible = true;
   txtPassword[e.RowIndex].Focus();
}
```

But in above solution characters are displayed.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work to handle the EditingControlShowing event and in the handler add the following code:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex == 2)
{
    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.PasswordChar = '*';
    }
}
```

CellFormatting Event Handler code:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex = 2)
{
    if(e.Value != null)
    {
        e.Value = New string("*", e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```

And in this event e should have a ColumnIndex property :)

Comment: The handler for the `EditingControlShowing` will have by default `DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e` as the second parameter, that's the one.

Comment: columnindex is not a member of DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs.
Can you verify?

Comment: sorry, mixed up the events a bit there, try something like `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex` instead

Comment: now it works..But when i shift to other row.It again reset to original text :(

Comment: For that you also have to handle the CellFormatting event, I'll update my answer with a sample.

Comment: CellFormatting does not work - it passes formatted value to editor (all stars), which then gets saved when editor closes. Will have to implement CellPainting and CellToolTipTextNeeded probably (I just did and it seems to work). Used yours EditingControlShowing, setting tb.Text

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create your own type of cell and assign that type to your password column. For example you'll add only the standard TextBoxPassword to it and then it should work as you wish.

On the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc06dx4f.aspx) there is more detailed description with source code available.

You'll just have to create your won kind of [CellTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell and column, and use a textbox with the password mask as your edit control.

To get around returning the clear text when you leave edit mode, you can store the actual password value in a seperate property of the cell, and in the GetFormattedValue event (i believe) you can return a string made up of entirely "*" characters  to mask the regular display.

```
Protected Overrides Function GetFormattedValue(ByVal value As Object, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByRef cellStyle As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle, ByVal valueTypeConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, ByVal formattedValueTypeConverter As System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, ByVal context As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object
        Dim strVal As String

        strVal = New String(CChar("*"), value.ToString.Length)

        Return MyBase.GetFormattedValue(strVal, rowIndex, cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context)

    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
    ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)

        MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, _
                                        dataGridViewCellStyle)

        Dim ctl As PasswordTextBoxEditingControl = _
            CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, PasswordTextBoxEditingControl)

        If IsDBNull(Me.Value) Then
            ctl.Text = ""


        Else
            ctl.Text = CType(Me.Value, String)
            ctl.PasswordChar = "*"
            ctl.Mask = "*"
        End If

    End Sub
```

for more information on what you are trying to do, visit this: 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=554744