# How to add password field in Grid View in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, passwords, field

I want to create password field in Data Grid view in WinForm c# .NET.

How should i proceed?

Comment: WPF?  Windows Forms?  ASP.NET?

Comment: Is this the windows datagridview or the web gridview?

Comment: I think my answer to the same question here would work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735811/how-to-create-column-of-type-password-in-gridview/2735858#2735858

Answer (score 1):

If it's for creating a password and you *must* do it in the grid, just use plain text and clear it out once you create the account.

If you're building an app where a customer service rep builds an account for a user, either send the user a password you generate or use some default password for your company (I would only use this with internal-use-only software).  Then force them to change it on the user's first login.

I can only assume you don't want the ability of your grid users to view passwords.  If indeed that is the case, **don't do it!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It may helpful to  you.

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
    string pwd = new string('*', row.Cells[2].Text.Length);
  }
}
```